# django-websocket-redis development server not working

Tags: django, websocket, redis

I'm working on a Django app that's using the `django-websocket-redis` app to publish events from the server side.

I've successfully configured a test server using `nginx` and `uWSGI` to route both HTTP and WS requests correctly to my Django app, but on my local development environment I cannot get this working.

According to the `django-websocket-redis` [documentation](http://django-websocket-redis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running.html#django-with-websockets-for-redis-in-development-mode), it's enough to start the Django development server and everything should work fine, but it seems like this is far away from reality.

Here is what I've checked:

- redis is running on `localhost:6379` and is responding to `PING` requests
- tried to run the server on different ports (80, 8080, 8000) to check if the `django-websocket-redis` makes any assumption about the development server's port, but nothing changed
- searched for solution online, but there is nothing about this topic

On my local environment on the client side I see a 404 error when my app tries to connect to the local WebSocket. My `settings.py` sets the `WEBSOCKET_URL` to the correct URL (on test server it's working, but locally isn't).

Anyone has an idea what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround to this.

I've modified my wsgi.py to this and it works now:

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")

# This application object is used by any WSGI server configured to use this
# file. This includes Django's development server, if the WSGI_APPLICATION
# setting points here.

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from django.conf import settings
from ws4redis.django_runserver import WebsocketRunServer


if settings.DEBUG:
    _django_app = get_wsgi_application()
    _websocket_app = WebsocketRunServer()

    def application(environ, start_response):
        if environ.get('PATH_INFO').startswith(settings.WEBSOCKET_URL):
            return _websocket_app(environ, start_response)
        return _django_app(environ, start_response)
else:
    application = get_wsgi_application()
```

UPDATE: it's not needed to create a custom management command as I mentioned previously, so I've deleted that part of the answer.